# RedirectToAction retcode error handling best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    int retCode = Errors.SUCCESS;
    var da = this.GetDataAccess();
    var ids= new List<Models.Users>();

    retCode = da.GetId(this.GetId(), ref ids, profiler);
    return this.CheckIdForView(nRetCode, View(ids));

}

public ActionResult DeleteUser(string id)
{
    var da = this.GetDataAccess();
    var ids = new List<Models.Users>();
    int retCode = Errors.SUCCESS;

    retCode = da.DeleteId(this.GetId(), id);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

}

Obviously in the delete user action the retcode gets erased as soon as it redirects to the index action.  I was wondering what the best practice for preserving a retcode like this is.  I've seen a lot of talk about TempData, but is that the bestpractice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it in the querystring to an optional parameter in `index`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? retCode = null);

return RedirectToAction("Index", new { retCode });
```

Comment: @ SLaks, should be `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { retCode=retCode });`

Comment: @Chris: No; it doesn't need to be.

Comment: +1 @SLaks, oh didn't know that. So if they are both same it works as you've put? Cool thanks. Learn something new everyday. Agree with your answer too then although `=null` default value is also not needed.